# Are ActiveJobs methods instance or class methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have my job class and was wondering if I could define a helper method in such way that the variables initialized in one task are not seen by the next task that runs that job.

In other words, is the following thread safe?

```
class OrdersUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base

  def perform
    p my_method
  end

  def my_method
     @sth ||= 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have class methods and instance methods. As any class, class methods definition starts with self.

```
ActiveJob::Base.methods.select{|m| m == :perform}
=> []
ActiveJob::Base.instance_methods.select{|m| m == :perform}
=> [:perform]
```

There's no "perfom" method on the base class, but there's one perfom method on the instance methods.

I think that what you are asking is if the jobs are run by a class or an instance of that class. Seeing that only instace_methods includes :perform, I'd say that ActiveJobs are run as instances. So you should be able to use instance variables with no threading conflicts.

Comment: Thanks! a good comparison: `ActiveJob::Base.singleton_methods.sort.grep(/perform/)` vs `ActiveJob::Base.instance_methods.sort.grep(/perform/)`